# Reading ID3 data of MP3 files encoding issue

Tags: c#, .net, taglib-sharp

I'm using TagLib to read ID3 data.

I can't read data properly from ID3 tag when they contain cyrillic characters.
(I'm getting something like `"²íòó³ö³ÿ"`).

Here is my code:

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(songFileName);
string title = f.Tag.Title;
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Which version of ID3 are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use this method to process your strings. It works fine for me when the string isn't empty and contains Russian or English letters.

```
    public string ConvertToUtf8(string unknown)
    {
        return new string(unknown.ToCharArray().
            Select(x => ((x + 848) >= 'А' && (x + 848) <= 'ё') ? (char)(x + 848) : x).
            ToArray());
    }
```

[Source](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread356693.html)